# Get array items by index

Tags: c#, arrays

I have two arrays, one with values an one with indices

```
int[] items = { 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 13, 16, 19, 23, 25, 26, 29, 31, 35, 36, 39, 45 };
int[] indices = { 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9 };
```

now I want a result array from the `items` selected by the indices of `indices` array

```
// 2, 7, 9, 13, 19
int[] result = new []{ items[1], items[3], items[5], items[6], items[7], items[9] };
```

Question: Is there a more generic approach for this?

Comment: btw; this is also sometimes called a "gather", especially in the context of vectorized intrinsics (AVX etc): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectored_I/O

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var results = Array.ConvertAll(indices, i => items[i]);
```

Comment: What if i is >  items.Length or negative?

Comment: @LewsTherin then it'll throw (presumably `IndexOutOfRangeException`), which I would say is correct behaviour if your `indices` is invalid

Answer (score 3):

Try using *Linq*:

```
int[] items = { 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 13, 16, 19, 23, 25, 26, 29, 31, 35, 36, 39, 45 };
int[] indices = { 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9 };

int[] result = indices
  .Select(index => items[index])
  .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

A good old for loop should be able to do this job as well:

```
int[] items = { 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 13, 16, 19, 23, 25, 26, 29, 31, 35, 36, 39, 45 };
int[] indices = { 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9 };

List<int> resultList = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < indices.Length; i++)
{
     resultList .Add(items[indices[i]]);
}
```

Explanation:

when using the `[ ]` operator to access a specific index in `indices` it will return the number. This can again be used to index/access a specific location in `items`. So you have a double indexing.

EDIT:

If you need the result as an array you can use the [ToArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819(v=vs.110).aspx) method to convert it:

```
int [] result = resultList.ToArray();
```

Comment: I suggest turn `results` into array (as in the question): `int[] results = new int[indices.Length]; ... results[i] = items[indices[i]];`

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of alternative:

```
int[] result = items.Select((value, index) => new { Index = index, Value = value }) //Add indexes
                    .Where(w => indices.Contains(w.Index))                          //Filter by indexes
                    .Select(s => s.Value).ToArray();                                //Extract values to result array
```